# How to find Latitudes and Longitudes for an address to create google map in web page?

Tags: .net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to integrated google map in my web page, it should show map for adddress traced from database. So I can not use a certain location to generate map. It seems that for each address, google map api need Latitudes and Longitudes to draw the map. But how do I know Latitudes and Longitudes from an address? Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the the geocoder section of the google maps api v3 will aid in completing your task

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Answer (score 0):

You should try using Google's geocoding service:

[Documentation here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/):

**Please read the TOS and Usage Limits**. Basically, if you let each webpage send the geocoding request, rather than doing that server-side, you should be ok.

By the way, Google Maps API does allow passing an address to it, AFAIK, in order to get the marker on the map. See the details in the documentation on the

[Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html)

There are other geocoding services also available:

[Yahoo PlaceFinder](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/)

and others